# connect to unix socket dgram width a socket file in nodejs like php socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0), but it does not work

Tags: node.js

I encounted an udp dgram connection problem with a sock file.I have to translate a udp dgram connetion from php way to nodejs.But all failed after trying all kinds of ways.

The php code is just like this:

```
$this->socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
socket_connect($this->socket, '/tmp/agent.sock')
...
socket_write($this->socket, $data, $total_len)
```

I have tried many ways.
**1. use net module:**

```
const net = require('net');
const client = net.createConnection('/tmp/agent.sock')
```

but get 'Error: connect EPROTOTYPE' error.

**2.use unix-dgram npm package.**

```
var unix = require('unix-dgram');
var client = unix.createSocket('unix_dgram');

client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});

client.connect('/tmp/agent.sock');
```

but get error bellow:

```
node: ../src/unix_dgram.cc:299: Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Send(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE): Assertion `node::Buffer::HasInstance(buf)' failed.
```

**3. use http.request:**

```
const http = require('http');
const options = {
  socketPath: '/tmp/agent.sock',
  path: '',
};
const callback = res => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', data => console.log(data));
  res.on('error', data => console.error(data));
};
const clientRequest = http.request(options, callback);
clientRequest.end();
```

but also get **Error**:

> 'Error: connect EPROTOTYPE' error.

I have no idea how to fix it, so badness.

Comment: you are trying to make socket connection on the same machine right?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? Send data as a buffer.

```
var unix = require('unix-dgram');

    var client = unix.createSocket('unix_dgram');
    client.connect('/path/to/socket');
    client.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
    client.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
        client.on('congestion', function() {
            console.log('congestion');
            /* The server is not accepting data */
        });

        client.on('writable', function() {
            console.log('writable');
            /* The server can accept data */
           let message = Buffer.from('PING');
          client.send(message);
        });


});
```